# Converting Year Day Month to Month Day

Tags: sql-server, date

Wondering if anyone could help with a problem I am getting in SQL Server.

Below is what I am trying to change date from `2016-09-01` to `September 01` etc.

I am getting an error message when trying to convert the date.

```
set @start_date = '2016-09-01'
set @end_date = '2016-11-21'

SELECT pol AS [Policy], 
DATENAME(MONTH, pol_dt) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, pol_dt)AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [Policy Date]
from pol_t
where pol_dt>= @start_date
and pol_dt<= @end_date
```

Comment: which SQL server version?

Comment: What is the type of `pol_dt`? It should be `date` or `datetime`.  Are you sure the problem is in the `SELECT` clause instead of the implicit casts in the WHERE clause? Change your variables' types to dates and assign values using an unambiguous format eg: `declare @start_date date='20160901'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ...

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, SYSDATETIME())+ ' ' + RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(DAY, SYSDATETIME()), 2) AS [Month DD];
```

Comment: What and why have you changed? Why don't you format the query? More info: [answer]

Comment: Welcome and  mention not

Answer (score 1):

IF 2012+ You could use format

```
Declare @D Date='2016-09-01'
Select Format(@D,'MMMM dd')
```

Returns

```
September 01
```

Format() has some great functionality, but it is not known for its performance

Comment: Given that 2012 is the earliest supported version, this answer holds for all supported SQL Server versions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Very true, but I'm still shocked at the number of questions for 2008 and below.

Answer (score 0):

Month DD 1

SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [Month DD]

January 2

This is a great link for all things related to SQL Server and Date formatting.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx